# Fetch dropdownlist selected value upon click of a button

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

On an ASP.net form, I have a button and a Dropdownlist. The Dropdownlist is populated through a LinqDatasource.

I am trying to get the selected dropdownlist value upon click of a button.

The dropdownlist gets the list of lastname from employees table of Northwind db.

The code behind is like this which gets the ddl value as null

aspx page

```
 <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Demo._Default" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl_allGoldsets" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" DataTextField="LastName" 
    DataValueField="LastName">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="Demo.linqDataContext" EntityTypeName="" GroupBy="LastName" 
    OrderGroupsBy="key" Select="new (key as LastName, it as Employees)" 
    TableName="Employees">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

codebehind

```
namespace Demo
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            linqDataContext dc = new linqDataContext();
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("Ddl_allGoldsets");
            string val = ddl.SelectedValue;

            /* code that writes val into db*/
        }
    }
}
```

Above code returns null value into ddl!!

Comment: What are you databinding to your ddl? Remove that line and your code will probably work.

Comment: removed the  ddl.DataBind() line and still same error! thanks

Comment: Is there anything databinded to your ddl in your postback?

Comment: Please post aspx of those button and dropdownlist.

Comment: no databind! I just added databain based on some suggestion on SO. The data  source for the Dropdownlist is linqdatasource which basically gets list of strings. Dropdownlist gets populated perfectly well.

Comment: Does "gets the ddl value as null" mean that `ddl.SelectedValue` returns `null`, or that `ddl` is `null` and you get a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: yes, it does get NullReferenceException

Comment: added the complete aspx and codebehind

Comment: @user219628: In that case, roughnex's answer is correct: the control is not a direct child of the page. However, you shouldn't need to use `FindControl` at all; you should be able to refer to `Ddl_allGoldsets` directly from the code-behind.

Comment: Richard Deeming, you're right. I could access the DDL.SelectedValue from the codebehind without doing any search. Thanks. If you can write same as answer, I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `FindControl` at all. You should be able to refer to `Ddl_allGoldsets` directly from the code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = Ddl_allGoldsets;
    string val = ddl.SelectedValue;

    /* code that writes val into db*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your dropdown is not immediately under the Page control. The form falls under the Page control. And your dropdown will be under the form control.

As a result

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("nameofDropdownlist");
```

looks for a ddl named "nameofDropdownlist" directly under the root of the aspx. But it is inside the form tag.

It's better to wrap the ddl inside a PlaceHolder and use FindControl on the PlaceHolder Id.